# Why does this search URL redirect to a different search URL when copied and pasted?

Tags: python, url, web-scraping

Web-scraping adjacent question about URLs acting whacky.

If I go to glassdoor job search and enter in 6 fields (Austin, "engineering manager", fulltime, exact city, etc.. ). I get a results page with 38 results. This is the link I get. Ideally I'd like to save this link with its search criteria and reference it later.

https://www.glassdoor.com/Job/jobs.htm?sc.generalKeyword=%22engineering+manager%22&sc.locationSeoString=austin&locId=1139761&locT=C?jobType=fulltime&fromAge=30&radius=0&minRating=4.00

[image]

However, If I copy that exact link and paste it into a new tab, it doesn't act as desired.

It redirects to this different link, maintaining some of the criteria but losing the location criteria, bringing up thousands of results from around the country instead of just Austin.

https://www.glassdoor.com/Job/jobs.htm?sc.generalKeyword=%22engineering+manager%22&fromAge=30&radius=0&minRating=4.0

[image]

I understand I could use selenium to select all 6 fields, I'd just like to understand what's going on here and know if there is a solution involving just using a URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change of `URL` seems to happen on the server that is handling the request. I would think this is how it's configured on the server-side endpoint for it to trim out extra parameters and redirects you to another `URL`. There's nothing you can do about this since however you pass it, it will always resolve into the second `URL` format.

I have also tried [URL shortener](https://bitly.com/) but the same behavior persists.

The only way around this is to use Automation such as Selenium to enable the same behaviour to select and display the results from the first `URL`.